# Custom Twig tag; could not find base class __TwigTemplate_

Tags: templates, twig

I'm trying to create a custom Twig tag (http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#tags) for my custom website system.

By using the following tag in a template:

`{% entity '\\Testimonial\\Entity\\Testimonial' with { 'limit' : 2, 'column' : 'created' } %}`

The custom tag will load the last 2 Testimonials from the database ordered by the column created. Ok, so far so good.

For the TokenParser I used code from the include tag:

```
class Entity extends Twig_TokenParser
{
    public function parse(Twig_Token $token)
    {

        $object         = $this -> parser -> getCurrentToken() -> getValue();

        if( empty($object))
        {
            return;
        }

        $expr           = $this->parser->getExpressionParser()->parseExpression();

            $variables      = $this->parseArguments();

        return new EntityNode( $object, $expr, $variables, $token->getLine(), $this->getTag() );
    }
    protected function parseArguments()
    {
        $stream = $this->parser->getStream();

        $variables = null;
        if ($stream->test(Twig_Token::NAME_TYPE, 'with')) {
            $stream->next();

            $variables = $this->parser->getExpressionParser()->parseExpression();
        }

        $stream->expect(Twig_Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);

        return $variables;
    }
    public function getTag()
    {
        return "entity";
    }
}
```

And for the Node I've borrowed from include and some other examples I've found resulting in:

```
class EntityNode extends Twig_Node implements Twig_NodeOutputInterface
{
    public function __construct( 
                    $object,
                    Twig_Node_Expression $expr,
                    Twig_Node_Expression $variables = null, 
                    $lineno, 
                    $tag = null )
    {
        parent::__construct(array('expr' => $expr, 'variables' => $variables), array("object" => $object), $lineno, $tag);
    }
    public function compile(Twig_Compiler $compiler)
    {
        $compiler->addDebugInfo($this);

        $obj        = $this->getAttribute('object');

        if( !is_callable( $obj ) || !class_exists( $obj ))
        {
            // error not callable
        }

        $entities   = forward_static_call( array( $obj , "TemplateEntity" ) , $this -> getNode( "variables" ));
        $subtemplate    = forward_static_call( array( $obj , "TemplateEntityTemplatePath" ));

        $template   = new Twig_Node_Expression_Constant( $subtemplate , $this -> getLine() );
        #return;
        $compiler
            -> write("\$this->env->loadTemplate(")
            -> subcompile($template)
            -> raw(")")
            ;
    }
}
```

The result is an error from Twig saying it can't load the basetemplate:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in /domains/<domain>/lib/framework/vendors/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php(328) : eval()'d code on line 370
0 - Exception occurred

Exception -- Autoloader could not find base class __TwigTemplate_c56f3794ae5aed2d0cc25529303a838625ded364d30febb96cd025a5d7622121
```

I know everything works correctly until the Twig_Node, the problem lies in how Twig parses the line `$compiler
                -> write("\$this->env->loadTemplate(")
                -> subcompile($template)
                -> raw(")")
                ;`

Hope to get some help from you guys; any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end Twig has a weird way of formulating errors in the code.

After careful considering other Node examples in the Twig node directory I noted the following missing `;` at the end of the compiler method `raw`:

```
class EntityNode extends Twig_Node implements Twig_NodeOutputInterface
{
    public function __construct( 
                    $object,
                    Twig_Node_Expression $expr,
                    Twig_Node_Expression $variables = null, 
                    $lineno, 
                    $tag = null )
    {
        parent::__construct(array('expr' => $expr, 'variables' => $variables), array("object" => $object), $lineno, $tag);
    }
    public function compile(Twig_Compiler $compiler)
    {
        $compiler->addDebugInfo($this);

        $obj        = $this->getAttribute('object');

        if( !is_callable( $obj ) || !class_exists( $obj ))
        {
            // error not callable
        }

        $entities   = forward_static_call( array( $obj , "TemplateEntity" ) , $this -> getNode( "variables" ));
        $subtemplate    = forward_static_call( array( $obj , "TemplateEntityTemplatePath" ));

        $template   = new Twig_Node_Expression_Constant( $subtemplate , $this -> getLine() );
        #return;
        $compiler
            -> write("\$this->env->loadTemplate(")
            -> subcompile($template)
            -> raw(");\n")
            ;
    }
}
```